# Changing the Intershop JumpTargets on an AJAX request

Tags: intershop

Is there a way to change the `JumpTarget` per request?

During the checkout flow the shipping methods are updated and a fresh cart is calculated.  I'd like to do the same with an ajax call on my customized checkout flow.  What I'm seeing is the jumpTarget is wrong and returns the wrong page:

1. Wrong: 
   `JumpTarget=ViewCheckoutAddresses-Review` returns payment page
2. Correct: `JumpTarget=ViewCheckoutShipping-Review` should return updated payment methods

==========

UPDATE:

All I needed to do was satisfy the pipeline params by including the correctly named 'name' field on the submit button.  I could also use a hidden field to set the jumpTarget.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually really hard to answer this question without actually debugging what is going on in your pipeline. I would suggest that you start the pipeline debugger and look what flow it follows. Then see what the standard checkout does (non ajax based) and see where your flow differs. It might just be that you are missing some input parameters and therefor it tries to send you back to the previous step.